# Coaxial/UTP Equalization Circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, video, transmission-line

I have a problem with a circuit that transmitts a video signal(PAL 1.0 Vp-p) through a coaxial cable of around 200m.My problem is that the high frequency content is really attenuated by the cable.I need to build an equalization circuit but I don't understand how I will do it because the attenuation doesn't appear only at a certain frequency,so i will need to correct every "frequency".Could somebody give me some advice about this,where do I need to put the equalization circuit(transmitter/receiver) and how do I suppose to do this ?I thought at an active high-pass filter but this will work only for a certain frequency.

Comment: What precisely is your signal re bandwidth. I know it's PAL but can't be bothered to research it. 5MHz and 200m sounds really lightweight BTW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll do just fine with equalization. RG59 (Belden 8212) is pretty good coax and you can find the attenuation figures [HERE](http://www.arrg.us/pages/Loss-Calc.htm) for virtually any commonly available coax - it's a calculator so just plug the numbers in i.e. frequency, cable length etc. and bingo out pops the attenuation: -

[image]

It's really not a hard cable to equalize up to 10MHz (attenuation about 6.5 dB at 10 MHz and I would suggest that pre-emphasis is the best way to go (then your receiver isn't going to be too upset).

So, plot out the counter-response you need and make a peaking filter that roughly matches the emphasis you need to apply. Use (free) LTSpice for this or any PSpise software to hand.

I've had to do this for 660 Mbps over 50m of very good coax but it still benefitted from a bit of emphasis. In the end we decided to use CAT7 but the idea was proven as far as I am concerned.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.I have one more question how do I suppose to do this ? I mean if i will built a high pass filter only the frequency above the cut off frequency will pass, instead the PAL signal has frequency from 50Hz to 6 MHz.How could I deal with this ?

Comment: Yeah what I meant was a peaking filter that rises about 6dB between 1MHz and 10MHz. Above 10Mhz you should make a decent attempt to roll off as per a low pass filter hence why I am now calling it a peaking filter.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your cable is properly terminated, you don't need an "equalization circuit" to fix this but an amplifier aka [repeater](https://www.google.com/search?q=coaxial+repeater&tbm=isch). Or possibly several along the way.

Amplifiers are ideally located along the cable, but often this is impractical, so the sender/amplifier equalizes the signal in the reverse profile of the cable loss vs. frequency. You can look at a block diagram of such an amplifier,e.g. http://evertz.com/products/manual/7700ADA7-EQ.pdf

Note that PAL-I bandidth for a single TV channel is about 8MHz (AM-VSB modulation).

If you want to build an equalizing amplifier from scratch, you can look at datasheets of (wideband) video amplifiers. For example [VCA821](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/vca821.pdf) has this suggested application for a given cable:

[image]

The cable attenuation graph is actually flipped (along the horizontal) in that figure in order to show how the amplifier matches (and in reality reverses) it.

Comment: The cable is a RG59 coaxial cable and at 5 MHz and 200 meters you have almost -6dbm, so from the original signal you will have 1/4 from the original signal.That's why i want to amplify/equalize the signal.

Comment: That sounds like a lot of attentuation at 5 MHz. Maybe you meant at 50 MHz? Look at http://media.extron.com/download/files/specs/rg59-spec_062409.pdf for some figures.

Comment: Ok, you are right is about -3.6db at 200m, but i need amplification for this because is more than half of the signal.

Comment: I see. Amplifiers are ideally located along the cable, but often this is impractical, so the sender/amplifier equalizes the signal in the reverse profile of the cable loss vs. frequency. You can look at a block diagram of such an amplifier,e.g. http://www.evertz.com/products/manual/7700ADA7-EQ.pdf However if only care about a narrowband signal (at 5 Mhz say) the don't to worry about equalization.

Comment: I made some tests and if the signal at 5 MHz is half from the original signal a lot of video content is wasted and so the quality.

Comment: Also, you could consider RG-11/U cable instead which can work without an amplifier till about 500m.

Comment: The problem is that my application has a specific cable and I can't change the cable.

Comment: If your application cannot handle an attenuation of only 3.6 dB, then you need to rethink your system.

Comment: This is a video signal of 1V peak-to-peak any attenuation of high freaquency component will degradate the quality that's why I need an equalization circuit to compensate this loss.

Answer (score 1):

Video equalizing amplifiers are commercially available - just google for that term to find lots of sources.  When I search for video equalizing amplifier, one link is to a Linear Technology design note DN92 (www.linear.com/docs/4289) which briefly discusses the design of such an amplifier (using a Linear IC).

Comment: I looked at that application note but i want just to understand how that feedback network formed by resistors and capacitors work.I want to undestand logically.Thank you.

Comment: @Stefan Merfu: Alas I don't think such a hand-holding appnote has been written (I've been searching for one). You'll have to undestand feedback network, poles and what not before you can design it yourself. I'm hoping there might be simpler (IC-based) solution, but I haven't found one yet. Something about RF engineers being "real men" and all that.

Comment: There are some solutions like MAX7474 but this is hard to provide from Farnell and other markets than DigiKey.

Comment: @Stefan Merfu: Also if you look at the block diagram (Figure 74 in the datasheet) of VCA821 (from my answer), you'll recognize that it includes the three opamp configuration shown in the Linear appnote. Also, it looks like you found a pretty good (if not outrigth better) solution yourself with the MAX7474.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear to me if whether or not you can tolerate a 3rd party box between your circuit and the cable, but if you can, then what you want is often called a 'launch amplifier'  e.g.  http://www.viotran.co.uk/cctv%20video%20amplifier%20coaxial.html

As others have pointed out, for baseband video you should probably be thinking more about amplifiers than equalisers.

Does your circuit have a buffer to drive the cable/termination?  Can you up the gain at that point?

Comment: My application doesn't support a 3rd party box only ICs and especially op amps circuit because they are more easy to provide.

Comment: What are you driving the cable with - you usually have x2 gain at that point anyway, to compensate for the 75ohms at each end of the cable - can you turn that up a bit further?

Comment: On the other side i have a video capture device that accepts a max voltage of about 1.5V, I could do an attenuation there but i think that is not practical.he gain is of course x2 due to the termination method.All i want is that somebody could explain me how this equalization circuit(feedback network) works in order to compensate along this frequency(0-6 MHz), I don't use the audio carrier.

Comment: The equalisation is just a high-pass filter, with a slope which is arranged to match the cable's frequency-dependent attenuation.  You could imagine it as a high-pass filter set at zero Hz but with a very gentle slope and very weak attenuation in the stop band  *BUT* for it to have any merit in your system, you need have enough gain overall, and what you're being told is that you'll probably find that the gain is enough, without worrying about adding a slope to it.